# Overflow property is not applied to body element

Tags: html, css

My problem is that when I set `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` on body element nothing really happens. I tested this on chrome and firefox. It works fine for div elements, but for some reason does not work for body.

You can see what I mean on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ulan/b2ap5j86/)

[image]

So my question is if anybody knows why is this happening and how to solve it for body element?

Comment: set body `width` to `100%`

Comment: Set `overflow: hidden;` for `html` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should solve your issue.
You need to apply overflow: hidden; on both `body` and `html`

https://jsfiddle.net/b2ap5j86/2/

```
table {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively you can use div wrapper for your elements and apply `overflow: hidden` on that, I would suggest this approach as you have better control, example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/b2ap5j86/3/

Comment: thanks GibboK! This indeed solves it, but do you know why it doesn't work just for body element?

Comment: you mean width, in this particular case?

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows the content overflowing the body element horizontally.

Comment: I think @BoltClock actually answered the "why" part.

Answer (score 3):

From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow):

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the 'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport, if the value on the root element is 'visible'. The 'visible' value when used for the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'. The element from which the value is propagated must have a used value for 'overflow' of 'visible'.

In short, setting a value for `overflow` on just the body element causes that value to be transferred to the viewport, which in turn causes the body element itself to have `overflow: visible` as the used value.

Changing `overflow` on both html and body prevents the body element from losing its specified value, because then the viewport takes the value from the html element as opposed to the body element.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew this!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid green;
  table-layout:fixed;/*************define  table-layout****/
  width:100%;   /*************define width here****/
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
 /*  width: 100px; /*********remove width here***************/
  padding: 5px;
  
  width:10%;/*************define width here****/
}

body {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div{
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: first run your code and compare outputs